# 401 error - Not able to update Jenkins plugins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

we're getting the following error when trying to update the Jenkins plugins. we've proxy configured
"
Failure -
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: [https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/active-directory/2.26/active-directory.hpi"](https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/active-directory/2.26/active-directory.hpi%22)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edc2i.png)

Answer (score 0):

401 status code means failed authorisation.
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2

Try verifying your username password once.
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/active-directory/2.26/active-directory.hpi is globally accessible.

A simple wget from the jenkins machine will download the new plugin if the proxy is configured correctly.